# Is the OpenGl subsystems activated in Colab?

Tags: opengl, google-colaboratory

I set the DeepMind lab scripts as indicated in github.com/deepmind/lab. I've got the following error: **XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment. GLimp_Init() - could not load OpenGL subsystem.**

I proceeded then as suggested in the following site to solve the issue with the configuration, but still getting the same message (unable to open display) --- https://askubuntu.com/questions/872792/what-is-xdg-runtime-dir.

I would appreciate very much some advice on how to activate (if possible) the OpenGL configuration in Colab.